# Read data from json response through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, google-maps

I am doing an `ajax` call to get longitude and latitude from a pin code.I did like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=753010,India&sensor=false",
                data: {},
                dataType:"json",
                success: function (results) {
                    console.log(results);
                    console.log(results.length);
                    //alert(results.geometry.location.lat);
                    //alert(results.geometry.location.lng);
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
```

I got the response as per the below image

[image]

But I am not able to get longitude and latitude by using this `results.geometry.location.lat` also I have tries `results[0]`.

Please help to find longitude and latitude. Also if I am not wrong location gives proper longitude and latitude.

Comment: It's `results.results[0].geometry.location` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results) :

> When the geocoder returns results, it places them within a (JSON) results **array**. Even if the geocoder returns no results (such as if the address doesn't exist) it still returns an empty results **array**.

Pay attention that returned JSON may contain multiple values, it's wisest to iterate over the length of the results array if you want to capture all possible values. In practice, you may wish to only access the first result `results[0]` locations.

`results.results[0].geometry.location.lat` and `results.results[0].geometry.location.lng` accordingly.